# Bake script works individually, but crashes in loop

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I am trying to write a script to bake all of my physics in the correct order. The commands work if I issue them to each cache individually, but if I try to bake them all in a loop, I get a `Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`

The script is as follows:
import

```
 bpy
from bpy import data as D, context as C

for objName in ('StickManDefender', 'Blood1', 'Blood2'):
    obj = D.objects[objName]
    print(obj.name)
    for mod in obj.modifiers:
        if mod.type == 'DYNAMIC_PAINT':
            ctx = C.copy()
            for surf in mod.canvas_settings.canvas_surfaces:
                print(surf.surface_format)
                if surf.surface_format == 'IMAGE':
                    ctx['object'] = obj
                    bpy.ops.dpaint.bake(ctx)
                    break
                elif surf.surface_format == 'VERTEX':
                    ctx['active_object'] = obj
                    ctx['object'] = obj
                    ctx['point_cache'] = surf.point_cache
                    print('Free Bake')
                    bpy.ops.ptcache.free_bake(ctx)
                    print('Bake')
                    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(ctx, bake=True)
```

The output is:

```
StickManDefender
IMAGE
Blood1
VERTEX
Free Bake
Bake
DynamicPaint: Preparing UV surface of 256x256 pixels and 16576 tris.
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

If I limit the run of the script to only 1 of the objects, no problems. As soon as I try to bake multiple in a loop, crash. I've tried using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to run each iteration on a separate thread and wait for the result before continuing the loop and I've tried running the whole thing on another thread, but no dice. I've also tried calling `C.scene.update()` between iterations, but that doesn't help either. Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: As an aside, I've worked around this by putting a numeric property on an object as an iteration counter and running the script multiple times. I'd prefer a single run.